# Checkbox with Thymeleaf and custom List Object in Spring MVC (Boot)

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf with Spring Boot and MVC. What I have is a form in which certain checkboxes are being populated with an object(q1) added into the model from the controller

What I want to know is that how can I bind the selected checkboxes with my resulting object(surveyData) into a list of (complex) objects using Thymeleaf properly.

**Edit**
Also this is the first time I'm working on this combination of Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring JPA and entirely the first time I have used Thymeleaf. I'm not exactly sure where the problem may be. I did try debugging a **lot** but was unable to figure out where the problem is exactly. I tried various different combinations to get this working and got various different outcomes(mostly exceptions of course). It would be difficult for me to post all of them here so if you can suggest something I would love to try it out and post its result.

What I have till now: (The th:field for checkbox is obviously not working)

**Code:**

HTML Snippet:

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/controlleraction}" method="post" th:object="${surveyData}">
  <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action" id="table-resp">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="act,iter : ${q1}">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="check" th:value="${act.optionId}" th:field="*{keyResponsibilities.optionId.optionId}" />
        </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

SurveyData.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey_data")
public class SurveyData implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "some_id")
    private Long someId;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "key_responsibilities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "data_id"))
    private List<KeyResponsibilities> keyResponsibilities = new ArrayList<>();


    public List<KeyResponsibilities> getKeyResponsibilities() {
        return keyResponsibilities;
    }

    public void setKeyResponsibilities(List<KeyResponsibilities> keyResponsibilities) {
        this.keyResponsibilities = keyResponsibilities;
    }
}
```

KeyResponsibilities.java

```
@Embeddable
public class KeyResponsibilities {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "option_id")
    private OptionsMaster optionId;

    @Column(name = "other")
    private String other;

    public OptionsMaster getOptionId() {
        return optionId;
    }

    public void setOptionId(OptionsMaster optionId) {
        this.optionId = optionId;
    }

    public String getOther() {
        return other;
    }

    public void setOther(String other) {
        this.other = other;
    }
}
```

OptionsMaster.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "options_master")
public class OptionsMaster implements Comparable<OptionsMaster> {
    private int optionId;
    private String text;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "option_id")
    public int getOptionId() {
        return optionId;
    }

    public void setOptionId(int optionId) {
        this.optionId = optionId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "text", length = -1)
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OptionsMaster o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getOptionId(),o.getOptionId());
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your DEBUGGING tell you about WHERE the problem is ? Spring-MVC, Thymeleaf, JPA API, somewhere else? You have debugged that haven't you?

Comment: Please see the edit in my post.